# Sample from distribution taking spherical statespace

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, spherical-geometry

I have a probability distribution over a 2-sphere, with density function $f(\phi)$, a function of polar angle only. Is there an efficient way to sample from this distribution?

Comment: That makes no sense. The density function for a two-dimensional manifold must be a function of two variables. It may not depend on one of them, but unless you specify the second variable, you haven't defined a distribution. E.g., a density $\rho(\phi,\theta)\mathrm d\phi\mathrm d\theta=f(\phi)\mathrm d\phi\mathrm d\theta$ would specify a different distribution than a density $\rho(\phi,\sin\theta)\mathrm d\phi\mathrm d\sin\theta=f(\phi)\mathrm d\phi\mathrm d\sin\theta$. Probably you meant the former?

Comment: I indeed meant the former. I apologise for the unintended ambiguity.